# Strange error in my java code with httpconnection

Tags: java, http, http-get, httpconnection, openjdk-11

I write this code:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
public class Main{
        private static HttpURLConnection connection;
        public static void main(String[] args){
                final URL url = new URL (spec: "https://google.com");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection =url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                int status = connection.getResponseCode();
                system.out.println(status);
        }
}
```

And get this error:

```
Main.java:8: error: ')' expected
```

I work with OpenJdk:

```
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and UBUNTU 18.04

**Thanks for any help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
public class Main{
  private static HttpURLConnection connection;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final URL url = new URL("https://google.com");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
    int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(status);
  }
}
```

I don't understand what is 'spec:' IDE hint or smth ? System should be from capital as well.

Answer (score 0):

A few things are wrong here, not handling exception, it should rather be something like this:

```
public class Main {
        private static HttpURLConnection connection;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                final URL url = new URL("https://google.com");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                int status = connection.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println(status);
        }
}
```

Comment: `Main.java:7: error: ')' expected 
  final URL url = new URL(spec: "https://google.com");`

Comment: I try it. It did not help

Comment: Terminal offers to put a bracket after spec

Comment: Edited the answer